# Meteor templates, check if value equals string

Tags: javascript, templates, if-statement, meteor

Here's the template structure

```
{{#each loadedEvents}}
  {{#if future}}
    {{#if timezone="Europe/Warsaw"}}
    {{> event}}
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Is that possible to view only items with given value?
And the second question, how to combine this two statements:

```
{{#if future}} {{#if timezone="Europe/Warsaw"}}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a dedicated helper to check if a timezone is equal to a certain value :

```
Template.loadedEvents.helpers({
  timezoneIs: function(timezone){
    return this.timezone == timezone;
  }
});
```

If you want to combine two Spacebars `{{#if}}` block helpers, once again create a dedicated helper that performs the test in JS :

JS

```
Template.loadedEvents.helpers({
  isFutureAndTimezoneIs: function(timezone){
    return this.future && this.timezone == timezone;
  }
});
```

HTML

```
{{#each loadedEvents}}
  {{#if isFutureAndTimezoneIs "Europe/Warsaw"}}
    {{> event}}
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have moved conditions into helper code, and differed results with #if and #unless :)

Answer (score 9):

Use `Template.registerHelper` to create a global helper. For instance, to create a helper that compares two arbitrary variables:

```
Template.registerHelper('compare', function(v1, v2) {
  if (typeof v1 === 'object' && typeof v2 === 'object') {
    return _.isEqual(v1, v2); // do a object comparison
  } else {
    return v1 === v2;
  }
});
```

Then use it using:

```
{{#if compare timezone "Europe/Warsaw"}}
     // Do something
{{/if}}
```